# laravel carbon time Modifier

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

i have time in seconds, using toDateString() function in am getting result in   00:14:46.

But in want in human readable format : 0 hours, 14 minute and 46 sec.

tried using secondsToTime(), but not working.

Comment: Are you making a comparison against a time in the future?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No.     i have time in Database stored in seconds . eg - 886.      using carbon toTimeString()  i am getting output -  00:14:46.  which is correct.  but in want in string format- like - 0 hours 14 min and 46 sec

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP `explode` to create an array and output the index values.

```
$timeArray =  explode(':', '00:14:46');
$myFormat = $timeArray[0]." Hours, ".$timeArray[1]." Minute, ".$timeArray[2]." Sec";
dd($myFormat);
```

**OR**

You could use this. I modified fubers 's answer.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('00:14:46')->format('h \H\o\u\r\s, n \M\i\n\u\t\e\s, i \s\e\c\o\n\d\s');
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: not working. it's giving 5 hours. as output. i don't want difference.